# Empirically demonstrating the Bias/Variance tradeoff.

Tags: variance, bias

I'd like to experimentally show that the Bias/Variance tradeoff holds. I tried to do it with modeling a complicated function cos(1/x) using different orders of polynomials but my results were not satisfactory.

Would appreciate any resources to people who's done this experimentally.

[image]

Comment: What was unsatisfactory about the results?

Comment: Maybe you could check a video from the "Learning from data" MOOC. I think it was covered there

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev seen those -- studied it in Grad school -- but not the formal proof